# Unknwon app named "Program" in startup apps, how to identify executable?

Tags: windows-10

I have a very strange entry in the Startup Apps System Settings (see below) named "Program". How do I find out which executable it is?

There are no entries in personal startup folder (`Win-R` `shell:startup`). There a two in common startup (`shell: common starup`) but they are also listed in system setting separateley

[image]

Comment: Look up Microsoft SysInternals. From there, download and run Autoruns.  This will normally give you more information about the program you see.  Run a Full complete scan with Windows Defender.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go and check the registry key of automatically start program of following paths:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   ```
2. Once started, kindly check if the unknow program is running under startup tab of task manager.
   If yes, right-click on the column header and enable these two options: Startup type and Command line, then you will get the full path.

   [image]